# How to blit image in pygame while using opengl?

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl

I'm trying to blit my character image using pygame, it works when opengl is not called

```
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    def draw(self,display):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 30:
            self.walkCount = 0
        if self.left:
            display.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount // 6], (int(self.x), int(self.y)))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            display.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount // 6], (int(self.x), int(self.y)))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            display.blit(standing, (int(self.x), int(self.y)))
        pygame.display.flip()
def redraw():
    global WalkCount
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    Player1.draw(display)
while True:
    redraw()
pygame.quit()
```

When opengl is called,

```
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGLBLIT)
...
def redraw():
    global WalkCount
    Player1.draw(display)
while True:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    redraw()
pygame.quit()
```

it doesn't show my character image anymore, how do I fix it? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing anything?

Yes. `pygame.OPENGLBLIT` is [obsolete](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_flags) and simply does not work (not sure if it ever worked; I guess not).

So either use a "regular" display surface or use OpenGL only.